# How to evaluate list view data from outside adapter in android

Tags: android, listview, android-recyclerview, android-adapter

I am showing math tables(One table) in list view and bottom of list view i have one button.
I am showing 10 rows in list view. Each row contains "1 x 1 = __" , "1 x 2 = __" ......etc. In Each row i can enter value in edit box.
When i click on button i want to evaluate rows results are correct or not.

Is there anyway to do this?

```
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.practice_fragment, null);

   mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recycle_view);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    mAdapter = new PSimpleRecycleAdapter(getActivity(), sNumbers, sTableName);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the button is not part of any recyclerView item. In this case you can do this by:

```
buttonValidate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mAdapter.validateInputs();
        }
    });
```

Then in your adapter simply cycle through all the items ad compare the entered value with the expected and make some UI changes to the items.